# Unable to create a pandas dataframe from a json list due to presence of a colon in one of the values

Tags: python, pandas

The code below works fine with other list objects, but here due to the presence of a colon in `imageURL`, it's giving me an error. I have to load the data dynamically without looking at the particular key value pair. Please help.

```
dt=[{'lineno': '3544', 'sku': 'B2039P015DP', 'status': 'Shipped', 'order_qty': '4', 'openQty': '0', 'wipQty': '0', 'shippedQty': '2', 'closedQty': '0', 'closed_date': '', 'returnedQty': '0', 'deliveredQty': '0', 'imageUrl': 'https://d2p3w.cloudfront.net/pub/media/catalog/product/b/2/b2039p010ds.jpg', 'itemName': 'Primo Brown Cube Box, 5Ply, (20"x10"x10"), Pack of 15', 'price': '1033.76000', 'udf1': None, 'udf2': None, 'udf3': None, 'udf4': None, 'udf5': None, 'internalLineNo': '1'}]
dummy = pd.read_json(json.dumps(dt),orient='records')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `json.loads` to load it rather than `pd.read_json`.
So with your input `dt` this code works fine:

```
dummy = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(json.dumps(dt)))
```

Comment: Or, you know, just don't JSON it at all... `dummy = pd.DataFrame(dt)`